# NodeJS storing iterator position over requests

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops, express

We have written some code that returns an array from a database and on the first request, we loop over it until we find the variable. and then send that value.

However, if we also have a second request that request starts iterating at the position we left the previous loop on.

```
result.findAllLights(function (lights) {
            console.log("got callback");
            var send = false;
            delete lightId;
            console.log("PRE-LOOP = " + JSON.stringify(lights));


            for (var lightId in lights) {
                console.log("checking " + lightId);
```

and this produces

```
checking 0
light.column=0 and row = 0 and 1 and 1
checking 1
light.column=0 and row = 1 and 1 and 1
checking 2
light.column=0 and row = 2 and 1 and 1
checking 3
light.column=0 and row = 3 and 1 and 1
checking 4
light.column=0 and row = 4 and 1 and 1
checking 5
light.column=1 and row = 0 and 1 and 1
checking 6
light.column=1 and row = 1 and 1 and 1
found light
```

and when the second request is in this is the output

```
checking 7
light.column=1 and row = 2 and 1 and 1
checking 8
light.column=1 and row = 3 and 1 and 1
checking 9
light.column=1 and row = 4 and 1 and 1
checking 10
light.column=2 and row = 0 and 1 and 1
checking 11
light.column=2 and row = 1 and 1 and 1
checking 12
light.column=2 and row = 2 and 1 and 1
checking 13
light.column=2 and row = 3 and 1 and 1
checking 14
```

Comment: Reduce the scope of your variable, move it inside your function. Also prefer `const` use over `var` it help prevent scope issue.

Comment: Could you show `PRE-LOOP` from the log?

Comment: Watch out, [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) iterates over object properties, use [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) if you want to iterate over arrays.